# <font> tag for Android Accessibility > High contrast text

Tags: android, html, fonts

I'm using `Html.fromHtml()` method to format text for my text view. When I turn on *Accessibility > High contrast text* option, I noticed that all my attributes for `<font>` do not work any more. For instance, `<font color="yellow"></font>` has no effect.

Anyone has the similar experience?

Comment: The `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5. You should not use it.

Comment: thanks @mbomb007 hmm.. `<font>` works for `Html.fromHtml` if `high contrast text` option is turned off. also, i didn't find any extra info from the api doc. this API is pretty old - level 1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String). I suspect it is related to this new `high contrast text` option on Android?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I'd bet that the using CSS for font and color, even if inline, would be more likely to work.